# Array not filling with .Split Method

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I am having an issue getting the array "*whyWontYouWork*" to populate with a value.  In the following example, the value of *rangeNames[j]* is **"$A$1:$A$10"**.
the string "*group*" will fill in correctly as **"$A$1:$A$10"** but the line above it shows up as "The name 'whyWontYouWork' does not exist in this context", so I am at a loss since it works once, and when I try to split the string, I get nothing.   Any ideas?

```
private void CutStates(string[] sheetNames,string[] rangeNames, string[] idNums)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Workbook wkbk = null;
        wkbk = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

        for (int i = 0; i < idNums.Length; i++)
        {
            string stateId = idNums[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < sheetNames.Length; j++)
            {
                string[] sheet = sheetNames[j].Split('!');
                List<string> rowsToDelete = new List<string>();
                List<string> reverseDelete = new List<string>();
                string tabName = sheet[0];
                string[] whyWontYouWork = rangeNames[j].Split(':');
                string group = rangeNames[j];

                Excel.Range range = wkbk.Sheets[tabName].Range[group];
                foreach (Excel.Range cell in range)
                {
                    string val2 = cell.Value.Substring(0, 2);
                    string cellAdd = cell.Address.ToString();
                    if (val2 != stateId)
                    {
                        string delCell = cell.Address.ToString();
                        rowsToDelete.Add(delCell);
                    }
                }
                reverseDelete = rowsToDelete.ToList();
                reverseDelete.Reverse();
                foreach (string item in reverseDelete)
                {
                    Excel.Range delete = wkbk.Sheets[tabName].Range[item];
                    delete.Delete();
                }
            }//j
        }//i
    }
```

I plan on using the first part ($A$1) as the starting point of a group to delete from the top down, and the second part ($A$10) to be the starting point from the bottom up to delete.

I want to iterate through the cells in "group" one at a time and if the first two characters don't match the two character stateId.  At that point I move to the next until I find one that matches, move back one row grab that address and then grab the start of the list ($A$1) and select from there to the last row that doesn't match, and  delete the block.  I will do the same for the row after the last match to the end ($A$10).  I would do this line by line but I do this over 15K rows so one at a time is terribly slow.  I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: To clarify, Console.WriteLine(rangeNames[j]) prints $A$1:$A$10

Comment: The variable is not used at all. The compiler may have completely optimized that line of code away based on Release / Debug mode.

Comment: What line does it give you this error on?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking or what the problem is, since you never use that variable for anything.

Comment: @David - please see edit.

Comment: @RonBeyer - string[] whyWontThisWork .....

Answer (score 1):

From code it seems you are iterating through sheets (`for (int j = 0; j < sheetNames.Length; j++)`) so it is possible that for first sheet you have rangeNames[j] value ("$A$1:$A$10") and on other sheets you don't.

From what I remember Excel by default creates 3 sheets, so that's probably the problem.

Comment: I should have pointed out that the sheetNames are pre-entered by the user and have little or nothing to do with the three tabs created by default, but I can see why it would look that way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to A few of you pointing out that the variable wasn't used, I checked my settings and it was optimizing the variable away.  I thought I had changed that.  Adding a simple console.writeline (instead of using the Watch) pushed the variable into use and made it stick.